# `r` permutations of `n`

Tags: javascript, combinatorics

I have written this snippet to find r-permutations of n, i.e. if I have an array of n=3 {0,1,2}, then r=2 permutations will be {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}}.
Can somebody review it and help me optimize / reduce its complexity (I don't want to use recursive function):

```
"_getAllPermutation": function(input, allPermutations, usedIndices, r) {
    var index = 0,
        usedIndex = null;

    for (; index < input.length; index++) {
        usedIndex = input.splice(index, 1)[0];
        r--;
        usedIndices.push(usedIndex);
        if (input.length === 0 || r === 0) {
            allPermutations.push(usedIndices.slice());
        }
        if (r > 0) {
            this._getAllPermutation(input, allPermutations, usedIndices, r);
        }
        input.splice(index, 0, usedIndex);
        r++;
        usedIndices.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to include either recursive calls or nested loops (and/or in-built functionalities performing this kind of actions). Just one suggestion: perhaps you should keep the nomenclature consistent to avoid misunderstandings (e.g., if you talk about k, include k in your code). Because this r is not too clear (mainly when it is being modified inside the function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you asked for a non-recursive version, but recursion is a natural way to approach this problem.  Here's a compact, though not high-performance, approach:

```
function nPr(xs, r) {
    if (!r) return [];
    return xs.reduce(function(memo, cur, i) {
        var others  = xs.slice(0,i).concat(xs.slice(i+1)),
            perms   = nPr(others, r-1),
            newElms = !perms.length ? [[cur]] :
                      perms.map(function(perm) { return [cur].concat(perm) });
        return memo.concat(newElms);
    }, []);
}
```

All we're doing is taking each element, and then appending it to the (r-1) permutations of all the other elements.

It is possible to do this using `while` and without recursion, though it will be hard to make that approach as terse.  I'll try to take a shot at it later.

Comment: After our talk yesterday (and after having seen various questions on this front during the last days), I decided to go ahead and write a loops-based in the way I like. It is a code which can become handy at a later stage (not too straightforward to write). If you want to take a look, I uploaded it to my GitHub account; I guess that you prefer the C# version (also a VB.NET one): https://github.com/varocarbas/permutations/blob/master/permutations/Program.cs You shouldn't find too many problems to understand it as far as is mostly formed by parts which are very similar in JavaScript....

Comment: ... I have also included the version with repetitions I mentioned yesterday (i.e., where the number of permutations results from the equation: elements_considered ^ size_permutation); you can enable/disable it with a simple flag (also you can see the required modifications + how easily I might change many other things; what I was telling you yesterday too). Logically, the whole point of this code is transmitting clearly the ideas (and easily allowing as many modifications as required) and is not over-optimised; but actually its performance seems equivalent to your code's one (even faster).

Comment: I replied in your github project.

Comment: And I re-replied there (I guess that we don't need to continue here :)). It seems that your repetitions are not right.